# How to tear down a Docker container using pytest fixture?

Tags: python, docker, automated-tests, pytest

With Python Unit testing, I would use the classical setUp and tearDown methods. I prefer though pytest as to use test parametrization with the data I get from the container.

To setup a container, I could use the fixture function. But how to tell it to destroy the container after test execution ends?

The following code works not as expected:

- Pytest seems to recreate the fixture for each test parametrization.
- As it seems, no actual container is created.

More words on what I'm trying to achieve:

- Need to test an ingredient parser, tests reflected in the variable `local_data`
- The ingredient parser is wrapped in the Docker container (fixture)

```
import pprint
import json
import requests
import pytest
import time


local_testdata = [
    ("1/2 of an apple", {"product": "apple", "unit": "item", "quantity": "1/2"}),
    ("12 oz frozen spinach", {"product": "spinach", "unit": "oz", "quantity": "12"}),
    ("24 oz frozen strawberries", {"product": "strawberries", "unit": "oz", "quantity": "24"})
]

def parse_ingredient(ingredient_string):

    ingreedy_path = "http://localhost:5000/query"
    for tupl in ingredient_string:
        payload = {"query": ingredient_string}
        result = requests.post(ingreedy_path, data=json.dumps(payload))
        obj = json.loads(result.text)


@pytest.fixture
def ingreedy_service():
    import docker
    client = docker.from_env()
    ingreedy = client.containers.create("openfoodbroker/ingreedy.service", name="ingreedy_service", detach=True)
    print("launch Docker container with Ingreedy service")
    time.sleep(2)
    pprint.pprint(client.containers.list())
    yield "ingreedy"
    print("destroy Docker container")
    ingreedy.remove()


@pytest.mark.parametrize("ingredient_string, expected_result", local_testdata)
def test_ingredient_parser_localdata(ingredient_string, expected_result, ingreedy_service):
    print()
    print("execute test for: [%s]" % ingredient_string)
    print()
    # result = parse_ingredient(ingredient_string)
```

Output:

```
launch Docker container with Ingreedy service
[]

execute test for: [1/2 of an apple]

.destroy Docker container
launch Docker container with Ingreedy service
[]

execute test for: [12 oz frozen spinach]

.destroy Docker container
launch Docker container with Ingreedy service
[]

execute test for: [24 oz frozen strawberries]

.destroy Docker container
```

Comment: How are you defining your container?

Comment: It seems your question is how to do teardown with pytest? That's simple; add a yield in the fixture to return control to your testcode. Anything after the yield is executed on teardown. More explanation in the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code)

Comment: Are you using [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) already? Or how are you controlling container currently.

Comment: @NiklasSaari MarkM thank you! with docker-py and yield this works now!

Comment: though it works not as expected. I update now the question body with example code.

Comment: @OpenFoodBroker try to use `@pytest.fixture(scope="session")`